# A linear operator satisfying the polynomial is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

I have come across the following problem states the following:

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on any real vector space $V$ such that $P(T) = 0$, where $P(x) = x^2 + x + 1$. Show that $T$ is invertible, and $v$ and $T(v)$ are linearly independent for any nonzero $v \in V$.

It's easy to write its inverse which is $-(T+I)$ but I am stuck on the second part. Any hint to start ?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that we have
$$a\mathbf{v} + bT(\mathbf{v}) = \mathbf{0}$$
for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. If $b$ were not zero, that would mean $b\mathbf{v}$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $-a/b$. But what do we know about the eigenvalues of $T$? Why is this a contradiction?